# My emulator only display the last image on my constraintLayout

Tags: xml

Here is my android studio phone (what i want it to display) 
[my andriod studio phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTonL.png)
   and here is my emulater phone
[my emulator phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqvPC.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqvPC.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqvPC.png`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView15"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/brownhole"
    tools:layout="editor_absoluteX="
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView21"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/bluehole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="180dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView16"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/redhole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="270dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/greenhole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="471dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView19"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/brownhole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="471dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView20"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/redhole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="180dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="471dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView17"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/bluehole"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="270dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="471dp" />`ays on the emulator on the top left screen
```

[my andriod studio phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTonL.png)

[my emulator phone shows only the last image on the constraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqvPC.png)

Comment: Plese share the related code. And take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You Have To add Constraints to all the element in Activity_main.xml if you are using constraint layout
FOR THAT
[Do As I shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNwsw.png)

If you don't add constraint Every Elemet will jumped to (0,0)